# Why doesn't Capybara raise exception when block is passed to find() but raises one when block is passed to within

Tags: ajax, rspec, capybara

We are having some troubles with our AJAX specs and `within` / `find`.

I'd like to do the following:

```
it 'allows to load more search results if there are any', focus: true, js: true do
  fill_in 'search_term', with: '*'
  click_button 'Search projects' # Sends a POST request

  within 'table.projects' do
    page.should have_content '1 of 2'
    click_link 'Load more' # Sends an AJAX request
  end

  within 'table.projects' do
    page.should have_content '2 of 2'
    page.should have_link('Load more', visible: false)
  end
end
```

Sadly, this doesn't work, because the 2nd `within` doesn't seem to wait for the AJAX call to complete, while the 1st one seems to wait for the "normal" POST request (non AJAX).

Using a `find` instead of the 2nd `within` seems to solve the problem:

```
it 'allows to load more search results if there are any', focus: true, js: true do
  fill_in 'search_term', with: '*'
  click_button 'Search projects' # Sends a POST request

  within 'table.projects' do
    page.should have_content '1 of 2'
    click_link 'Load more' # Sends an AJAX request
  end

  find 'table.projects' do # find instead of within here!
    page.should have_content '2 of 2'
    page.should have_link('Load more', visible: false)
  end
end
```

Is it generally a bad idea to use `within` when testing stuff that involves AJAX requests? And why should I ever use `within` instead of `find` then, as `find` seems to do the same that `within` does **AND** waits for AJAX?!

Thanks a lot for your opinions.

Comment: Code inside `find` block is simply not invoked. [Read the rubydocs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) :) Exception isn't thrown as this method accepts `*args`

Comment: Which is your Capybara version? Automatic synchronization was improved a bit in 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean with "Exception isn't thrown as this method accepts *args"?

Comment: It's a question, I don't get your answer! :P

Comment: I've tried to write an answer addressing it. Feel free to ask for clarification if needed

Answer (score 1):

Code inside block of `find` is simply not invoked as [`find` doesn't support passing block to it](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method). Exception isn't thrown as `find` method accepts `*args` but doesn't perform thorough enough parameter parsing to throw exceptions if you pass invalid parameters.

To make your second example working you can try to update Capybara to 2.1 as automatic waiting was improved in Capybara 2.0 and 2.1.

Also you should know that Capybara methods such as `have_content` wait `Capybara.default_wait_time` which is 2 seconds by default.

If you want to wait more than that you can modify `Capybara.default_wait_time` or use [`using_wait_time` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/DSL#using_wait_time-instance_method):

```
using_wait_time 5 do
  page.should have_content '1 of 2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this too...what works is if you do a find before your within. Finding the Ajax waits for the Ajax request to load. If it doesnt load, you'll get a stale element reference or something like that. 
You also might need to do a .keydown () to trigger the request ...thats what I have to do if I'm testing something like autocomplete.